# android: first activity and next activity of animation effects on the same time

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I solved it.if you need help,this is my email: emmets@foxmail.com

xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/newLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/oldLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

java code,it need to extend ActivityGroup:

```
LocalActivityManager localLocalActivityManager = getLocalActivityManager();
    paramIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Window localWindow = localLocalActivityManager.startActivity("flag", NewActivity.class);
    localWindow.addFlags(1);
    View localView = localWindow.getDecorView();
    localView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    newLayout.addView(localView);
 dAnimation upOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_up_out);
     Animation zoomEnter = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_enter);
newLayout.startAnimation(zoomEnter);
oldLayout.startAnimation(upOut);
```

Comment: "When at the beginning of the animation, bottom to display the next activity page, then the first page of the animation and the next page animation begin at the same time." What does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            final View l = findViewById(R.id.main);

            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    YourActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            a.setDuration(200);
            a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        // Do what ever you need, if not remove it.  
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // Do what ever you need, if not remove it.  
                }

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // Do what ever you need, if not remove it.  
                }

            });
            l.startAnimation(a);
        }
    });
```